# React no envia value de select

Tags: laravel, reactjs

estoy intentando enviar los valores de un Select, pero me los envia vacios.

```
import Select from 'react-select'
const CustomerGroupOptions = [
  { value: '1', label: 'Consumidor Final' },
  { value: '2', label: 'Gremio' },
]

formData.append('CustomerGroup', CustomerGroup)

<Col xs={12}>
              <Label className='form-label' for='CustomerGroup'>
                Grupo de Cliente:
              </Label>
              <Select
                id='CustomerGroup'
                name='CustomerGroup'
                isClearable={false}
                className='react-select'
                classNamePrefix='select'
                options={CustomerGroupOptions}
                theme={selectThemeColors}
                defaultValue={CustomerGroupOptions[0]}
              />
            </Col>
```

Los inputs los puedo enviar sin problemas.

Comment: Falta información: el componente Select lo creaste o es de alguna libreria? donde enlazas el state al componente? y el evento onChange?

Comment: jeje, creo que ya se por donde viene el error entonces, porque la información que falta es porque no estaba